# Do all set returning functions support implicit loop?

Tags: jquery

The following two statements are equivalent :

```
// #1
$('.tr_tab_code').children().removeAttr("disabled");

// #2
$('.tr_tab_code').children().each(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

In statement 1 there is no need to do a loop. I want to know if all functions which return a set of elements support implicit loop like in statement 1?

Comment: Not all of them. Please see [Iterating over jQuery and non-jQuery Objects](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/#sometimes-each-isn-39-t-necessary).

Comment: Where element-level context is not required, then yes. @Xufox's link explains it more clearly with examples.

Comment: @Xufox - Wow, that part of the documentation isn't very good. We don't need `each` in most of those cases, as most of them have a version accepting a function ([`val` example](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think the “Learn jQuery” series mentioned callbacks for getter and setter methods earlier. But I actually misinterpreted the question. It’s “Do all set-returning functions support implicit loop?”. None of the functions in the article are set-returning functions.

Comment: Most of the jquery methods that apply to a set effectively do `return this.each(` as the very first line.   So there's no *implicit* loop as it's *explicit*.  Your `#1` and `#2` aren't 100% equivalent as the second calls `.each` twice.

Comment: @freedomn-m - Good point, and it's worse than that. :-) It (effectively) calls `each` `1 + length` times: Once coded by the OP, and the other `length` times within the callback. And calls `$()` the same number of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of jQuery's *setter*/*mutator* functions work on the entire set, yes; the vast majority of its *getter* functions work only on the first element in the set (`text` is the big exception there):

```
$("selector").html("foo");       // Sets the content of ALL elements in the set
var html = $("selector").html(); // Gets the content of just the FIRST element
                                 // in the set
```

Of course, if you use that feature, you can't do something different for each element, because you're just passing in the one value. Sometimes you want to tailor things per-element. Most setters and mutators support passing them a function that will get called for each entry in the set; the return value of the function is then used to modify just the one element in the set. For instance, this takes the value of each input in the set and capitalizes it by calling [`val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function):

```
$("input").val(function(_, value) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
});
```

(Sadly, the jQuery documentation [gets that wrong](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/#sometimes-each-isn-39-t-necessary), saying that you need to use `each` to do that. If I get time, I'll do a pull request...)

That form is supported by `val`, [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function), [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/#html-function), [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function), ... nearly all of the setters/mutators.

Consequently, `$().each()` is probably the most overused method in jQuery's API. :-)

Comment: In your function's parameters, value is equals to $(this).val() (in $.each loop), but what is "_" parameter?

Comment: @JaxTeller - `_` is fairly common shorthand for "I'm not going to use this" (except, of course, for people who use UnderscoreJS or Lodash!). The first argument jQuery passes in this style of call is the index of the element.

Comment: @JaxTeller `_` is commonly used to denote an “unused” positional parameter. It’s just a regular parameter name (a valid identifier), i.e. you can still use `_`, but, by convention, shouldn’t. (This is not jQuery-specific, btw.)

Comment: Well, long time i'm using jquery and this is the first time i see that kind of use. Thanks for this, i'll not do $each anymore with that.

Comment: This may also help (it specifically mentions the `.html()` getter-vs-setter example and also that `.text()` is the odd one out): https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/

Comment: Unless you're processing 10s of 1000s or nodes per second (or at least attempting to), I wouldn't worry too much about micro-optimising your code regarding calling `.each( .. .val(x))` vs `.val(.. callback)`.  It's not even clear which would be the more efficient - it's just another way to to achieve the same result.

Comment: @freedomn-m - It's clear which is more efficient: The callback version, not `each`. But it's also clear that it doesn't matter the ***vast*** majority of the time, as you said. :-) I certainly wouldn't flag it on a code review. (I might mention it informally as an FYI.) I prefer it just because it's more concise and (to me) says what I'm doing more clearly.